# Searching multiple columns in a text_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

3.5 and ruby 1.8.7 
I'm trying to create a multiple search working with 4 columns (name,name2,last_name,last_name2), want to search in a text box my 4 columns but i don't want to create 24 conditions, is there any other way to do this or maybe creating a conditional FOR instead of 24 conditions

```
I want to search by
    name and name2
    name and name2 and last_name
    name and last_name
    last_name and last_name2
 ...
 There are 24 conditions
```

Actually my controller is working but i don't want to write 24 conditions , here is my problem

Here is my model is empty

```
  ****************Here is my model************

 class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

 end
```

Here is my controller

```
*************Here is my controller****************

class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
   def index
       @projects = Project.find(:all, :conditions => "(
                                     name LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\" OR 
                                    name2 LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\" OR 
                                last_name LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\" OR  
                               last_name2 LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\" OR
          (concat(name, \" \", last_name) LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\")OR
          (concat(name, \" \", name2    ) LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\")OR
    (concat(last_name, \" \", last_name2) LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\")OR
    (concat(name, \" \", name2, \" \",last_name, \" \",last_name2) LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\")OR
   (concat(name, \" \", name2, \" \",last_name) LIKE \"#{params[:query]}%\"))  ")
    end
end
```

Here is search form

```
*********************Here is my view

<div id="search-area">
  <div id="searchbox">
     <form name="search-form" id="search-form">
       <label for="query"><%= ('BUSCAR') %>
        <%= image_tag("loader.gif",
                     :align => "absmiddle",
                     :border => 0,
                     :id => "loader",
                     :style =>"display: none;" ) %>
      </label>
        <%= text_field_tag "query", params[:query], :autocomplete => 'on' %>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Someone can help me to convert this in a conditional for? or maybe other way to find 4 columns in a text_field_tag

Comment: Little Bobby Tables problem: what if I type exactly in the text_field_tag the following search query: "`whatever";DROP TABLE users;`"? SQL injection!

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Comment: ok but do you know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Many issues with your code, SQL injection, and not fully taking advantage of Rails cleaning methods for parameters for SQL queries, you should specify the params as an array and let Rails do the dirty work for you.

Like such:

`@projects = Project.where(%q[ lower(name) LIKE :keyword OR name2 LIKE :keyword], :keyword=>params[:query].downcase).all`

I added the extra downcase so the search becomes case insensitive, much better.

Comment: i tried your code and i got this message i'm using rails 2.3.5 : undefined method `where' for #<Class:0x7f1f8955d818>

Comment: PLEASE I need help someone can help me with this?

Comment: For rails 2.3.5, try using this: 

Project.all(:conditions=>[" lower(name) LIKE :keyword OR name2 LIKE :keyword"], {:keyword=>params[:query].downcase}])

Answer (score 0):

To build on DevDude's answer,

In your model:

```
def self.custom_conditions
where(%q[ lower(name) LIKE :keyword OR name2 LIKE :keyword],
:keyword=>params[:query].downcase).all
end
```

In your controller:

```
@projects = Project.custom_conditions
```